# How to reset app as "First run"

Tags: android, caching, intellij-idea

I have dialogs that pop up on first run of the app. Since I added the booleans to set to false after first run, evertime i run the emulater (directed to actual phone not virtual) the app runs fine but those dialogs don't show. What do I do?

this link: [[How to clean project cache in Intellij idea like Eclipse's clean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561826/how-to-clean-project-cache-in-intellij-idea-like-eclipses-clean][1])

Says to File -> Invalidate caches. Is this correct? While this not harm my project?

I'm a novice, take it easy :)

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be clearing the data from your application:

go to "Settings" and look for the  "Application Manager", apply the "Clear data" option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Elenasys! I didn't know it actually would show in the Application Manager because I didn't "actually" install it. Good to know! did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the settings in the Applications menu in the Android Settings. In the application you have options to clear the cache and any data the application might have saved, like your booleans.

Comment: Where exactly is that in Android Studio?

Comment: Its in the emulator, in the Android OS. Have you ever used Android?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were talking about the device. I thought you was refering to the intelijet application. Thanks for the put down...