# Generating signed APK outputs no file

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When generating a signed APK, no file is being output. There are no errors in the gradle build log as is attached below, so I don't know where to start with this problem.

Here's a video showing the phenomenon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuZvSRXe-b0

And here is the gradle console log:

```
   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]

    Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
    Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkReleaseManifest
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareCnPedantSweetalertLibrary13Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132340Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGithubChyrtaAndroidOnboarder06Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAds900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid900Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComKarumiDexter222Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComMikepenzAboutlibraries566Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComMikepenzFastadapter151Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComMikepenzFontawesomeTypeface4501Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComMikepenzGoogleMaterialTypeface2101OriginalLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComMikepenzIconicsCore2511Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComMikepenzMaterialdrawer464Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComMikepenzMaterialize051Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComOgaclejapanSmarttablayoutLibrary160Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComOgaclejapanSmarttablayoutUtilsV4160Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComPnikosisMaterialishProgress10Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComWdullaerMaterialdatetimepicker230Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareIoGithubYavskiFabSpeedDial104Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareNetDanlewAndroidJoda292Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareReleaseDependencies
    :app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:lintVitalRelease
    :app:prePackageMarkerForRelease
    :app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:collectReleaseMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:validateExternalOverrideSigning
    :app:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:assembleRelease

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL

    Total time: 3.483 secs
```

Comment: Same problem. I am using Studio 2.2. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @zackygaurav Yes, it was solved in Studio 2.2 Preview **2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use gradle scripts to assemble release apk to target path.
Here is the code:

```
android {
   applicationVariants.all{ variant->
      variant.outputs.each { output->
        if(variant.buildType.name.equals('release')){
            output.outputFile = new File('/Users/yourname/Desktop/', ’myapk.apk')
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting and invalidating cache:

[image]

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561826/how-to-clean-project-cache-in-intellij-idea-like-eclipses-clean):

Comment: I tried this but the files are still being put in the wrong directory. I guess it's a bug with the preview release of Android Studio 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 sometimes likes to output the file in the wrong directory. The files were being put in AndroidStudioProjects/AppName/app/build/outputs/apk, instead of the chosen directory in the popup dialog when trying to generate an APK.

Answer (score 0):

me too,just change your gradle 2.2.0-alpha1 to gradle 1.5.0 or other,can generate signed apk normally.

Comment: If you change to 1.5.0, **Instant Run** won't work. You'll have to suggest a better solution.

Comment: oh,Instant Run ? just use JRebel will be ok.