# ProgressLoggerFactory Error in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated Android Studio from 1.5 to 2.1.2. After updating Gradle Sync failed message is started showing up

> Error:org/gradle/logging/ProgressLoggerFactory

Following is the screenshot of error.

TIA

[image: Gradle processlogger error]

Gradle File

[image: Gradle File]

Comment: post your gradle file....

Comment: @ExceptionLover I attached gradle file. Please check.

Comment: clean the cache of android studio http://stackoverflow.com/a/17561908/3678308 and try again..........http://stackoverflow.com/a/17561908/3678308