# Strange Exception in java using Intellij IDEA IDE

Tags: java, compilation, noclassdeffounderror

I have been developing my project for months

Suddenly I no more can build my project and get:

`java: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/trove/TObjectIntHishMap`

Actually there is really no class named `TObjectIntHishMap` with `i` instead of 'a', and there is no such reference in my code either, moreover the exception is not supposed to pop at compile time.
I tried cleaning everything in my project with no luck

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a broken state was cached. Can you clear the caches?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to clean project cache in IntelliJ IDEA like Eclipse's clean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17561826/12567365)

Comment: I tried and it did not work