# Trying to execute a Java Main Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a monolithic project which contains three springboot projects inside, but I can't execute them. When I try right click + "Run Project" this option do not appear. When I Try create a run configuration pointing to the main classes the IDE do not find my main classes in the project.

I really have to execute it in the monolithic path, because it doest not work opening a window for each project

[Cannot execute by right click + run project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AkZr.png)

[IDE can't find my main classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbliS.png)

I just want to execute the project. I tried by right click + run project and create a run configuration

Comment: Hii Try to delete cache and build the project : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561826/how-to-clean-project-cache-in-intellij-idea-like-eclipses-clean)

Comment: delete the cache and build refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561826/how-to-clean-project-cache-in-intellij-idea-like-eclipses-clean

Comment: You can't run, because your depencies didn't set, Reload project and upload depencies, plugins for running not available. Check also your maven configuration on the right side on Intellij Idea.

Comment: Please check Maven tool window and add modules is they are missing.